# How to decrease popup size gradually while dragging in android?

Tags: android, popup, resize, drag

I need to create a demo in which a popup appears and when user drags that popup, it's size decreases gradually. The size depends on the distance covered by the user while dragging. The functionality is similar to PAPER application(FACEBOOK).
I am able to drag the popup by below code. but the code is not able to decrease the size of popup while dragging its reduces the size when the popup is released.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,
        OnDragListener {
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    private LayoutParams layoutParams;

    ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        img.setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.pinkLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.yellowLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            layoutParams = (LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
        int action = dragevent.getAction();
        switch (action) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + dragevent.getX(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            layoutParams.height = (int) dragevent.getX();
            layoutParams.width = (int) dragevent.getX();

            img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            System.out.println("Action drag started");

            /*
             * Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
             * 
             * System.out.println("Drag event started");
             */

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            System.out.println("Action drag entered");
            /*
             * System.out.println("Drag event entered into " +
             * layoutview.toString()); Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into "
             * + layoutview.toString());
             */
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            System.out.println("Action drag exited");
            /*
             * System.out.println("Drag event exited from " +
             * layoutview.toString());
             * 
             * Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from " + layoutview.toString());
             */
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            System.out.println("Action drag drop");
            // Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped");
            View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
            container.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

            System.out.println("Action drag ended");

            /* Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag ended"); */
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what should I do with my existence code to achieve the functionality mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For my answer to be 100% precise i would need to have a bit more details about your application's work. From what you've written I assume that the "popup" will move under your finger and you want to resize it when it's being moved.

The solution is pretty simple. There are two thing you must do to do it:

1. Create a dummy shadow builder class so it doesn't display any shadow when you move your view (changing shadow size is tricky, but from what i understand you dont need shadow at all...). You can do it like this:

   ```
   public class DummyShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

       @Override
       public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point touchPoint) {
       }
   }
   ```

   And use it as your shadow builder for dragging:

   ```
   DummyShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DummyShadowBuilder();
   view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
   ```
2. Control the size and position of dragged view inside

   ```
   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION
   ```

   Example using your old code:

   ```
   public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
       int action = dragevent.getAction();
       switch (action) {
           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
               //CONTROL POSITION AND SIZE OF DRAGGED VIEW

               //EXAMPLE USING YOUR OLD CODE (previously in ACTION_DRAG_ENDED):
               int x = (int) dragevent.getX();
               int y = (int) dragevent.getY();

               layoutParams.height = x;
               layoutParams.width = x;

               img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

               View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
               ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
               owner.removeView(view);
               LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
               container.addView(view);
               view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               break;
           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
               break;
           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
               break;
           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
               break;
           case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
               break;
           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
               break;
           default:
               break;
           }
       return true;
   }
   ```